# xpath query to parse html page

Tags: html, parsing, xpath

I have an html file that looks like

```
<HTML>
        <BODY>
            <TABLE width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td height="400" align="right" valign="top" class="text_rail_left"></td>
                    <td width="100%" align="left" valign="top" class="text_back_color"><table border="0" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0" width="100%"><tr>

                    </tr><tr>
                        <td width="100%" align="left" align="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" class="inside_heading_text">Train Names with Details</td>
                            </tr> <tr>
                                <td><b><BR><BR> SORRY !!! No Matching buses Found</b></td></tr>
                            <tr><td>
                            </td></tr></table>
                        <td align="left" valign="top" class="pad_self"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
                            <tr><td align="right" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr></table></td>
                        </tr></table></td>
                    <td align="left" valign="top" class="text_rail_right">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="10" align="left" valign="top"><img src="http://www.indianrail.gov.in/main_text_left_bottom2.gif" alt="" width="8"/></td>
                    <td width="100%" align="left" valign="top" class="text_rail_bottom"><img src="http://www.indianrail.gov.in/blank.gif" alt="" width="1" height="8" /></td>
                    <td width="10" align="right" valign="top"> <img src="http://www.indianrail.gov.in/main_text_right_bottom2.gif" alt="" width="8" /></td>
                </tr></table><body>
                    <FONT size=1>No. of Queries :  0839425885
                        , &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Server : YAMUNA
                        , &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Dated : 15-05-2014 Time:07:15:26 Hrs</font></td></tr></table></td></tr> </table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td align="left"valign="top"><table width="970" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr> <td width="9" align="left" valign="top"><img src="http://www.indianrail.gov.in/images/footer_upper_lft.gif" alt="" width="9" height="49" /></td><td width="100%%" align="left" valign="top" class="footer_upper"><table width="100%%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0"><tr><td align="center" valign="top" class="main_footer_upper"><a href="../index.html"  onclick="resetButton()">Home </a> | <a href="http://www.indianrailways.gov.in/railwayboard/" target="_blank">Ministry of Railways</a> |      <a href="../know_Station_Code.html" onclick="resetButton()">Trains between Stations</a> | <a href="../booking_Location.html" onclick="resetButton()">Booking Locations</a> | <a href="http://www.cris.org.in/" target="_blank">CRIS</a> | <a href="../about_Concert.html"  onclick="resetButton()">CONCERT</a> | <a href="../advertisement.html"  onclick="resetButton()">Advertise with CRIS</a> | <a href="http://www.indianrail.gov.in/images/rail-map.jpg" target="_blank">Railway Map</a> | <a href="../faq.html"  onclick="resetButton()">FAQ</a> | <a href="../sitemap.html"  onclick="resetButton()">Sitemap</a> | <a href="http://www.trainenquiry.com/Feedback.aspx" target="_blank" onclick="resetButton()">Feedback</a></td></tr><tr><td align="center"valign="top" class="copy_footer" style="padding-top:3px;"><span class="main_footer_copy"><a href="../copyright.html"  onclick="resetButton()">Copyright</a></span> &copy; 2010, Centre For Railway Information Systems, Designed and Hosted by CRIS | <span class="main_footer_copy"><a href="../disclaimer.html" onclick="resetButton()">Disclaimer</a></span><br />Best viewed at 1024 x 768 resolution with Internet Explorer 5.0 or Mozila Firefox 3.5 and higher</td></tr> </table></td><td width="9" align="right" valign="top"><img src="http://www.indianrail.gov.in/images/footer_upper_rgt.gif" alt="" width="9" height="49" /></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table><script type="text/javascript">anylinkmenu.init("menuanchorclass")</script>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

I want to write an xpath query to read the string

`SORRY !!! No Matching buses Found`

There's no unique class that identifies the class with the string. I tried the xpath query

```
@"//td[@class='inside_heading_text']/tr"
```

but it doesnt seem to work.

Can someone point me in the right direction? I'm using the ONO library in Objective-C to parse the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this would get you the container of the "SORRY" text

```
//*[contains(text(),'SORRY')]
```

I recommend firefinder extension for firebug (on firefox) for an easy way to try xpaths.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the firefinder extension!

Answer (score 1):

That's some ugly HTML you got there.

There are unclosed elements, repeated `td/@align` attributes, etc.  You're going to have to clean it up first if you want to use XPath.

If you can manually or automatically clean it up at least to this point:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HTML>
  <BODY>
    <TABLE width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td height="400" align="right" valign="top" class="text_rail_left">
        </td>
        <td width="100%" align="left" valign="top" class="text_back_color">
          <table border="0" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="100%" align="left">
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top" class="inside_heading_text">Train Names with Details</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <b>
                        <BR/>
                      <BR/> SORRY !!! No Matching buses Found</b>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td align="left" valign="top" class="text_rail_right"></td>
      </tr>

    </TABLE>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Then this XPath will select the "SORRY..." text given the `inside_heading_text` point of reference that you mention:

```
//td[@class='inside_heading_text']/../following-sibling::tr[1]/td[1]/b
```